# Rings in which $ab=0$ implies $axb=0$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, noncommutative-algebra

I'm sure there must be some standard term for (not necessarily commutative) rings $R$ in which $ab=0$ implies $(\forall x)\, axb=0$ (for example, this is the case if $R$ is commutative *or* is a domain).  What is this term?

Additionally, or alternatively, what about (two-sided) ideals $I$ such that $ab\in I$ implies $(\forall x)\, axb\in I$, i.e., ideals quotienting by which gives a ring as I just said?  Do they have a name?

**Edit:** I should probably also mention the stronger condition that $ab=0$ implies $ba=0$: such rings are called "reversible" (Cohn, "Reversible Rings", *Bull. London Math. Soc.* **31** (1999), 641–648).  Clearly, commutative rings and domains are reversible, and reversible rings satisfy the property I'm looking for a name for (because in a reversible ring, if $ab=0$ then $ba=0$ so $bax=0$ so $axb=0$).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most modern term for this is

> $R$ satisfies the $SI$ condition

This is seen in papers by Greg Marks, which I have found to be the most thoughtful and comprehensive recent papers discussing these things. For example , see [*A taxonomy of 2-primal rings*](http://ac.els-cdn.com/S0021869303003016/1-s2.0-S0021869303003016-main.pdf?_tid=90e1249a-0c76-11e6-89cc-00000aab0f01&acdnat=1461761585_ffdb1518446e91f90e703f41d9bcfc4e).

Earlier works used the following terms:

> $R$ is zero-insertive (zi)
>
> $R$ satisfies the insertion of factors property (IFP)
>
> $R$ is semi-commutative (conflicts with different usages in the literature)

Comment: I am now lost in a maze of twisty ring properties, all alike. Coming from commutative algebra, it fascinates me how people can memorize all these definitions, let alone work with them. Thanks!

Comment: Oh, viewing your profile I just learned about the "database of ring properties", which is a great idea!

Comment: @Gro-Tsen I'm glad you like it! I really need to get back to work on that website.

Comment: @Gro-Tsen well, not many people have these definitions in their heads at all times. This is a great example of a bunch of closely knit conditions that "tease apart" particular aspects of something that happens in a commutative ring. (The nilpotent elements forming an ideal) it's also nice to see the variety of examples it produces